# Array Arithmetic Issue in C

Tags: c, gcc, pointer-arithmetic

I have a C code in long file that is compiled using cc. But when I tried to compile on gcc it gives error. I took that particular code in small program and try to compile on cc but it failed over there.

Here is source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
     char unsigned   FileName[100];
     char            test[100];
     FileName[strstr(FileName,test) - FileName] = 0;   
     return 0;
}
```

This line is causing the problem:
`FileName[strstr(FileName,test) - FileName] = 0;`

error on CC is :

```
"foo.c", line 10: operands have incompatible types:
         int "-" pointer to unsigned char
```

and on gcc is :

```
foo.c:10: error: invalid operands to binary - Both are same.
```

But when I compile original file on CC it compiled and just give a warning. Like this:

```
"dbtprc.c", line 643: warning: argument #1 is incompatible with prototype:
        prototype: pointer to const char : "/usr/include/iso/string_iso.h", line 133
        argument : pointer to unsigned char
"dbtprc.c", line 643: warning: improper pointer subtraction
```

Can you please help why here it is giving warning "improper pointer subtraction" and sample program it is showing error?

Comment: What is `bar` and `foo` pointing to?

Comment: That's a horrible test, by the way.

Comment: First off, as Acme mentioned, neither bar or foo point to anything. Second, you're trying to subtract a char* from a char*?

Comment: `test` is not initialized. You should initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you missed to include `<string.h>` ??

If yes, the prototype of strsrt is guessed and by default it returns an int, hence the invalid pointer operation.

Otherwise, it appears that the signedness mismatch is the cause of the warning/error.
Use a `(char*)`cast before the two occurence of your table and it will go.

Comment: Thank you for reply.Yes, you are partially right. Adding string.h on CC, it works and gives warning. But on GCC it still complaining for the same

Comment: Please tell ,Alternate to do the same?

Comment: Alternate to do what ? Are you trying to avoid casts ?

Answer (score 1):

```
void * bar;
void * foo;
...
foo = bar + 1;
```

That's undefined behaviour, right there! You are referring to a memory location that wasn't even allocated.

**EDIT**:

Now you have another problem: even though you sucessfully declared both arrays, you failed to clean/initialize them. Only god knows what `strstr()` will return to you.

The problem you have compiling this code is that strstr() takes 2 `const char*` and you defined *Filename* as unsigned: `char    unsigned FileName[100];`

> char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);

Comment: Updated answer. Even if you fix the type of Filename, you still need to `#include <string.h>` on your file. Even though all of this will get your code compiled, I doubt it will do anything good.

Comment: Thank you karl for your help. Adding <string.h> solve the problem on CC but on GCC it still there.

Comment: Dear I just have to compile it :)

Comment: The 2nd tip was to define *Filename* appropriately: `char FileName[100];` since *strstr()* does not take unsigned. Have you done that?

Comment: It's important to all of us that you accept the answer that solved your problem. Good luck. And if you have another problem, please ask another question on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything called Array Arithmetic in `C`? Read this:

[Arrays are not Pointers](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html).

And see how to use [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/).

Comment: Thank you for reply. Besides this Arrays are not pointer but the issue is CC is compiling a piece of code and GCC is not compiling same source. So why is it happening ?

Answer (score 0):

An error or a warning is not much different, just showing how serious the compiler believes the issue is.

But why do you use `unsigned char` for the filename? That's in conflict with `strstr` which only handles `char*`, both for its parameter and return type.

That's what the compilers try to tell you, in different ways.